# How to upload Java Applet to SmartMX controller

Tags: nfc, microcontroller, smartcard

In one week I will have the following SmartMX controller: [NXP P5CD041](http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_card_ics/smartmx_dual_interface_controllers/series/P5CD041.html) (in NFC ring). As I understand it has 2 interfaces: ISO/IEC 14443 A Contactless Interface and ISO/IEC 7816 contact interface.

I have read that I can write Java Applet and upload it to this controller. But I don't understand how. As I unserstand, I can upload it only using ISO/IEC 7816 contact interface and it needs some wired programmer that will be connected to pins of this controller. Am I right?

Can someone explain me what equipment do I need to upload Java Applet to this controller? Can I do it wirelessly (e.g. using Android or some special device)?

Comment: I am very interested in the device itself. Where do you get an NXP P5CD041 inside an NFC ring?

Comment: @DominikSchürmann the China seller has mistaken. Instead of NXP P5CD041 I got 2 x NTAG203 :(. I'm very sad, because its security is very bad comparing to NXP P5CD041. I'm searching for some nfc ring with javacard too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between developing an applet for a contact card or for a contact-less card.

**Requirements :**

1. A Contact or contactless smart card reader [ACR122 is a Contactless reader & ACR38 is contact reader for example. There are also some readers that are dual interface]
2. The Java Card Development Kit : It's available in [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javacard/downloads/javacard-sdk-2043229.html).
3. An IDE (Optional) : *Eclipse* or *NetBeans* for example
4. A tool to Upload and install your Java Card applications (Optional) : [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) for example.
5. A tool to send and receive APDU commands to/from the card (Optional) : [OpenSCTool](https://www.opensc-project.org/opensc/wiki/QuickStart) for example.
6. JCOP Tools if your chio comes with a JCOP OS installed on it and you want to use proprietary packages and methods also (So it is optional also)

*Note that 3, 4 and 5 are optional because you can use the same Java Card Development Kit tools to do whatever you want. (But these tool are really more friendly than JCDK Tools)*

If you choose *Eclipse* as your IDE, you must add a plugin named [Eclipse-JCDE](http://eclipse-jcde.sourceforge.net/) to it, And if you choose NetBeans as the IDE, it has Java Card plugin installed by default [in new versions].

**An example :**

The is a simple procedure for a simple *helloWorld* applet (Java Card applications), it returns "Hello Wolrd" in reception of any command:

1- Write [this](https://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/) program in the IDE.

2- Assign a 5 to 16 byte number to the package and another one to the  application as their AID (Application Identifier) and compile the *.java* file to *.class* using Java Development Kit.

3- Convert the *.class* file of previous step to a *.cap* file using Java Card Development Kit directly or using those IDE plugins indirectly.

4- Insert your card in the reader (For contactless cards bring in the field of the reader) and upload and install that *.cap* file on the chip using GlobalPlatformPro command as below : (In this step you do Authentication procedure and you need some keys)

```
CommandLine:> gp -install "capFileAddress"
```

5- Use Opensctool to select your applet using its AID and send APDU commands to it and receive APDU responses from it :

```
CommandLine:> opensc-tool -s 00a40400[AID Length In hex][AID] -s [AnotherOptionalCommand]
```

**Notes :**

1- AID is a name for applications and packages on the card. It has a 5 byte mandatory part and a 0 to 11 byte optional part. Applet AID must be equal with its package AID in the first 5 bytes.

2- When you want to make a communication with your applet in your card, you first need to select it using a select command. and the all the others commands refer to that selected applet.

3- What is APDU? It is a protocol in which commands defined as a sequence of hexadecimal numbers. You use this commands to communicate with the cards.

4- OpenSCTool and GlobalPlatformPro has whatever you need. But if you want to write your own tool, you can use [PyScard](http://pyscard.sourceforge.net/) library for Python or *javax.smartcardio* package for Java programs.

Comment: So my chip has contactless interface that implements ISO/IEC 14443 A standard. It defines mostly physical layer and communication protocol which is ISO/IEC 7816. Using 7816 I can upload applet and send APDU commands.

Am i right?

Comment: ISO14443 is the communication protocol of your card. ISO7816 part 3 is the counterpart for contact cards. ISO7816 Part 4 defines a set of APDU commands that your card maybe support them and maybe not!The authenticatin, applet installation and deletion defined in a specificatin name GlobalPlatform.

Comment: So we can send GlobalPlatform/APDU commands to chip over ISO14443-4 (contactless) and ISO7816-3 (contact) communication protocols?

Comment: @SteelRat GlobalPlatform defines some APDU commands. ISO7816-3 and ISI14443-3 are not communication protocols, these are 2 standards that define protocols. As far as I know the protocols that defined in 7816 are named T=0 and T=1 and the protocol that defined in 14443 is named T=CL (Contactless). I'm not sure aboute the latter.

Answer (score 1):

> As I unserstand, I can upload it only using ISO/IEC 7816 contact 
>   interface and it needs some wired programmer that will be connected 
>   to pins of this controller. Am I right?

I haven't checked the datasheet of this part, but you should in any case be able to upload your applets via the ISO7816 interface. The "programmer" that you need is nothing more than a ordinary SmartCard reader. These are cheap. You can get them for around 12 €/$. When you go shopping make sure that it supports the PC/SC interface (95% of all readers do, but just check just in case).

If your SmartMX chip comes in form of a smart-card with integrated antenna for NFC then you're done. It will fit almost any reader. If you get the bare chip you have to hook up the ISO7816 signals: clock, data, power, reset and ground. Since the readers are so cheap you can just crack one open and solder some wires onto it. Keep them below 20cm.

> Can I do it wirelessly (e.g. using Android or some special device)

Maybe. The SmartMX will appear on a Android phone as a IsoDep tag. You can exchange the same data over NFC as you can exchange over ISO7816. Both interfaces speak the ISO7816-4 protocol. It is possible that access to privileged operations like installing/deleting applets is restricted on the wireless interface though.

Also you won't get the nice upload tools from the SDK for Android.

To develop applets you need the JavaCard SDK from Oracle. It comes with a emulator, so you can already try out some of the examples and run them. As far as I remember the SDK also contains a bunch of scripts that allow uploading applets to various Smart-cards including the JCOP/SmartMX.

You may also need authentication keys to install the applets. If so they should be supplied with the chips/cards.

Comment: Chip will come inside NFC ring, not smart card. I can't break the ring and connect to its pins. So I need wireless approach.

Comment: @SteelRat There is no difference between developing applets for a contact or contactless card. You just need a contactless reader. The uploading files and installing procedure is the same as for contact cards.